# How to add the custom security tag in all request in soapUi using groovy

Tags: soap, groovy, automation, soapui

*I have to insert the security tag in all the request inside the header. How do I automate?* because for every request I have to copy past manually which takes time to do for all the request

**Below is the Actual Request:**

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.sample.com/" xmlns:ws1="http://ws.test.sample.com/">         
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
```

**After adding the security tag:**

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:ws="http://ws.test.sample.com/" xmlns:ws1="http://ws.test.sample.com/">  
    <soapenv:Header>
          <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://doc.test.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://doc.test.xsd">
           <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password Type="http://doc.test.xsd">o9j1/hA/mkFTG0ODti</wsse:Password>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_manipulating_xml

Comment: hi @daggett can you please explain. I have gone through the above link , but not able to follow up.

Comment: You have to explain what you want to do. And better to share the code what you have tried so far. The case I imagine: read soapui project XML and add security header in each request. So, I shared the link how to manipulate XML.

Comment: Hi @daggett below the steps followed.
1. Project-> WS Security Config-> Outgoing security config 
2.Added new WSS->checked on Must understand check box
3.Added new WSS Entry-> added username and pwd  and pwd type passwordText.

In the Soap request , Right clicked and selected OUTGOING WSS security and selected the created security. 
The above was working fine , and the security tag is added successfully on request after applying , and received the res too. 
The question is , When i automate using groovy , wil the security tag will get added automatically ? or how its to be done